# Disk quota exceeded at my cpanel root of Magento website

Tags: magento-1.9, error, reports

The issue is that I am on unlimited shared hosting and there is a lot of unused disk space but I can not login to Magento backend or even add product to the cart or save any file at the root.

When I try to save any files (for example: cleanup.php) all I get is:

```
ERROR: Could not create file "cleanup.php" in /home/thewa2m2/public_html: Disk quota exceeded
```

I know Magento has a huge number of files but the directory `/public_html/var/report` cannot be opened, I am thinking too many duplicate of reports at the root directory of `/var/report`.

My question is: can I delete them? Will it affect my site?

how do I Stop my site from duplicating report or how do I stop unnecessary continuous report of my site?

my site still give me same report as paste below, please how do solved this issue?

a:5:{i:0;s:52:"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations";i:1;s:409:"#0 /home/thewa2m2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(179): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')

## 1 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

## 2 public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

## 3 public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

## 4 {main}";s:3:"url";s:102:"/skin/frontend/default/ma_libra_electronic/layerednavigationajax/images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"english";}

Comment: Some hosting providers add constraint on no. of files being hosted not their size, consult if that's the case.  Not sure if it's anyhow related to Magento except Magento does have a huge no. of files: )

Comment: You can safely delete report files, it will not affect your site.

Answer (score 2):

All the files in `var/report/` can be deleted. Once that is done, read a few of the newly created ones and try to fix the error that's creating them.

From your last paragraph, I'm guessing you mean there are so many files in  `var/report/` that you can't open it in your SFTP client.

If you have SSH access, I'd recommend deleting them from the command line. If you delete the `var/report/` folder in an attempt to remove all of them from your SFTP client, you must recreate the folder with the same permissions and owner/group as the original or Magento will crash with an **Error Processing Request** page because it doesn't have a `var/report/` folder to write to.

On "unlimited shared hosting" a common tactic is to not limit your content by bytes consumed but by either number of files created or inodes used. The reason for exceeding your quota should be available to you in cPanel, otherwise ask your hosting provider for help.

If your hosting provider barely supports Magento, the php garbage collection may not be working and you will have `var/session/` with about a million expired session files sitting in it.

Also, if you didn't enable cron jobs by setting up a cron table entry, and by setting up log cleaning, your database may be bloated beyond 2-3Gbytes of old detritus.

Comment: how do I Stop my site from duplicating report or how do I stop unnecessary continuous  report of my site?

Comment: You read the contents of the report to view the stack trace and error message at the top and search on stackoverflow or magento.stackexchange for that error condition. If if no one's had that issue, ask a new question about the error it's reporting and post the contents of the stack trace. Your Magento installation is having a continuous error condition and you stop the unnecessary reports by eliminating the unnecessary crash that's causing them to be created.

Comment: my site still give me same report as paste below, please how do solved this issue?

a:5:{i:0;s:52:"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations";i:1;s:409:"#0 /home/thewa2m2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(179): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to eliminate the problem and then do the rest. You can close also log functionality and you will have more space on your disk.

Run your cron and you should have more space. Be sure that your cron is running good and clean all unnecessary files and database records.

Comment: my site still give me same report as paste below, please how do solved this issue?

a:5:{i:0;s:52:"Front controller reached 100 router match iterations";i:1;s:409:"#0 /home/thewa2m2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(179): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')